# How to find coordinate before convert to image

Tags: opencv

The image size is 640 x 480
and resize to image using by resize() function.
See figure.
[image]

Set the coordinates in the dst image.
So my question is the coordinates want to know how to find that the location where the src image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It scales linearly, so function will look like:

```
Point2f getNewCoords(Point2f oldPoint, Size oldSize, Size newSize) {
    return Point2f(oldPoint.x * newSize.width / oldSize.width,
                   oldPoint.y * newSize.height / oldSize.height)
}
```